# JavaScript nested async function return result after manipulation

Tags: javascript, node.js

First of all i'm beginner in javaScript async and call back.

I did this method and work properly.

```
Test.prototype.test3 = function(callback) {

return apiClient.returnAllmember(callback);  

}
```

I need to return the result after jsonQuery

```
Test.prototype.test2 = function(name,callback) {

apiClient.returnAllmember(function(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log('ERROR', err);
        return;
    }

   return jsonQuery(name+'[**]', {data: data}).value
});
};
```

Comment: you can not return from asynchronous methods. you need to look at promises.

Comment: Why don't you call the `callback` anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried using promises? Makes all this stuff so much easier once you get your head round it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am sorry to break it to you, but that won't be possible with nodejs async model.

What you'll rather do is

```
Test.prototype.test2 = function(name,callback) {
  apiClient.returnAllmember(function(err, data){
    if (err){
      console.log('ERROR', err);
      callback(err)
    } else {
      callback(null, jsonQuery(name+'[**]', {data: data}).value)
    }
  });
};
```

What this implies is you don't try to return from a callback. Rather, you call your callback with the returnable data and continue processing in your callback.

Comment: You're missing an `else` there. Never call the `callback` twice!

Comment: @Bergi .. I'll rather add a return to that .. but a `return` might just make the code more awkward to read right?

Comment: I think that one should use promises so one doesn't have this problem at all :-) Sure, early `return` is just as fine and maybe even more common, `else` is more explicit.